# Can I create a symbolic link to a PowerShell profile so I can move it to a synced folder?

Tags: powershell

From what I've been reading, there is no option to change the location of my PowerShell directory. However, I'd like to move it to a directory I've setup to sync files via SkyDrive so that the profile is synced across multiple systems.

If I were to move the profile to my SkyDrive directory and then create a Symbolic link to it in the default location, would this work?

If there is a better solution available I'd love to hear it. However, this is the best thing I can think to do at the moment and I'm not even sure if it will work.

TIA

Comment: Could you use Mercurial + BitBucket, or some other web-enabled versioning system, and sync as part of the profile sourcing?

Comment: Perhaps an option and probably a good one. I've already managed a work around using SkyDrive for all my version control though so I'd be interested in an answer to this if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use symbolic links (file and directory) in conjunction with Skydrive, but I feel like this might be a Superuser question.

`mklink /d "c:\users\you\skydrive\powershellstuff\" "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell"`

Try a directory junction with `/j` if the former doesn't work.

http://www.ghacks.net/2012/04/24/how-to-add-external-folders-to-skydrive/

Comment: Honestly, I've found questions about this on StackOverflow, SuperUser, and ServerFault so I wasn't sure which to post it on. I did consider posting this there but since most of my work is server related I picked SF. No issue moving it if necessary though.

Comment: @CrabbyAdmin No worries. There is overlap sometimes. I'll leave it up to others as to whether this needs to migrated or closed or whatever.